# Roo spreadsheet parse exact header match

Tags: ruby, xlsx, roo-gem

I have a spreadsheet(.xlsx) where two columns have the headers 'Auction Status' and 'Status';

When I run:

`rows = sheet.parse(auction_status: 'Auction Status', status: 'Status')`

both columns contain the values for the 'Auction Status' value. My guess is that `parse` is finding the string 'Status' inside of 'Auction Status' and is considering that a match. Do you know how to specify that I only want the exact match for 'Status' in the `parse()` argument?

Please ask for more info if you need it, I tried to trim this down to only the necessary details.

------Edit-------

When I try Regex:

`rows = sheet.parse(auction_status: 'Auction Status', status: /^Status$/)`

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for /^Status$/:Regexp
```

Comment: Hi @wuliwong, any luck? I am facing the same issue.